# Delegate from WCF to external, non-windows service

Tags: wcf

We have a service using WCF and client credentials - when we communicate to other WCF services, we use delegation and it works relatively well.

However, we're now trying to integrate with a service written in Python / Linux - how can we forward credentials from WCF to this Python service? Can we somehow generate a signed assertion that the Python service can verify? (Assume the Python service has access to AD.)

Comment: Since you wrote nothing about the Python-Service i must ask you, have you read and tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/de-DE/0aac0110-187e-4a00-a597-f15b768cf16c/passing-client-credentials-to-wcf-service?forum=wcf)